# Subscribe as soon as possible to a second observable, but wait for the first one to emit - Angular / RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm in a case where I want to subscribe as soon as possible to two different obsevable, but wait for the first one to emit before the second one emits.

For instance I'm developing a chat application where I want to retrieve all previous messages stored on a DB, but also subscribe to a stream which emits new ones.

I want something like this:

```
readonly messages$ = this.service.getStoredMessages().pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.service.getNewMessages())
)
```

The problem with this is that I may miss some messages because of a late subscription to `getNewMessages()`. What I need to do is to subscribe as soon as possible to both observables, but the second one (`getNewMessages()`) should emits only after `getStoredMessages()` emits.

Comment: If you want to both subscribe immediately, but not emit until the first one emits, what exactly is it that you want to do with emissions from the second observable before the first one emitted? It seems like switchMap(To) does what you want. Can you provide example observables and expected output?

Comment: @IngoBürk I think that what the OP is saying is that `getStoredMessages` is a pull request that sends a snapshot of the "historical" messages. However, it's possible that other messages get created while the request is being served. I've been in that situation, and what I did was buffer the messages that were received before receiving the result of the historical data, and then "merge" the historical with the buffered messages (ensuring that there are no duplicates), then emit those and afterwords emit the new messages. I could be wrong, but I think what's the OP is looking for.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but should still come from the OP. In that case I'd go for combineLatest (forkJoin won't work as I assume getNewMessages doesn't complete) with operators to combine the results.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late replay. What @Josep says it's correct. Would you mind sharing a solution with combineLatest? I don't quite get it how it could actually solve my problem. Again, sorry for the late replay

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti I disagree with @IngoBürk... I don't think that `combineLatest` is going to help you for what you are trying to do here, but now that you've confirmed that this is what you are looking for I will share a way to solve this. Although, I'm genuinely curious to see if I'm missing something, and `combineLatest` can help here.

Comment: Great! Thank you both :)

Comment: @Josep It depends on how nitty gritty you want to get here. To make this absolutely bullet proof you'd need to first subscribe to new messages, have the timestamp of since when you are subscribed and then request stored messages which are older than that timestamp. This is because you cannot account for what happens during network latency for request/response. That requires more than what this question currently offers as a frame, though. Edit: or you need to be able to deduplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `storedMessges$` type is `Observable<Message[]>`
- that `getMessages$` type is `Observable<Message>`
- and that `messages$` type is supposed to be `Observable<Message>`

I think that you are what you are want to do is something more or less like this:

```js
readonly messages$ = defer(() => {
  const storedMessages$ = this.service.getStoredMessages().pipe(share())
  const newMessages$ = this.service.getNewMessages().pipe(share())

  const missedMessages$ = newMessages$.pipe(
    takeUntil(storedMessages$),
    toArray(),
  )

  const initialMessages$ = merge(
    storedMessages$,
    missedMessages$
  ).pipe(mergeAll()) // instead of `mergeAll` maybe you want to `scan` and make sure that there are no duplicate values...

  return merge(
    newMessages$.pipe(ignoreElements()), // it ensures that we don't unbscribe from newMessages$ after storedmessages$ emits/completes.
    concat(initialMessages$, newMessages$),
  )
})
```

Comment: I think this is as close to correct as the question allows. The deduplication you mention is necessary, though, if OP really wants to be 100% sure that the result is correct.

Comment: Yes @IngoBürk, you are correct! However, in order to do the deduplication I would need to know more about the types of the observables... Usually each message has a timestamp, so assuming that the API sends them sorted chronological order, it should be fairly easy to do the deduplication... That's why I added a comment suggesting to use `scan` instead of `mergeAll`. I did the best I could given the amount of info provided by the OP :)

Comment: In this example what is the use of defer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of structure:

```
readonly messages$ = this.service.getStoredMessages().pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.service.getNewMessages())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this  :

```
readonly messages$ = this.service.getStoredMessages().subscribe(
              res => {
                      this.service.getNewMessages()
                     })
```

Comment: I don't like this, simply because it's a nested subscription and I don't think it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i understand is that there is an array of messages which you want to use in your view.

Let's call it `viewMessages`. Now if we want to push messages into `viewMessages`, I recommend subscribing both the streams i.e. stream of previous messages and stream of chat message and when any of them emits, prepend or append messages/messages into `viewMessages`.

```
viewMessages:Message[] = [];
.
.
.
this.getStoredMessages().subscribe(messages=>{
    const chatMessages = this.viewMessages;
    this.viewMessages = [].concat(messages, chatMessages);
});
this.getNewMessage().subscribe(message=>{
    const existingMessages = this.viewMessages;
    this.viewMessages = [].concat(existingMessages, message);
});
```

Please not the sequence is maintained in both the subscriptions. Previous messages will appear first and new messages will appear afterwards.

Comment: Maintining  two subscriptions with an external variable which represents the state of the stream isn't really a good practice from an Angular point of view. Plus I'm not sure if I am understanding correctly how the order of messages between old and new ones is kept. Is there no way I can combine those observable in a single subscription?

Comment: You are right that Maintaining multiple observables in a component can lead to memory leaks. But here you also need to know that the httpClient library completes the observable when is delivers a value. so technically any observables from HttpClient need not be unsubscribed.

Comment: For the observable which delivers new messages, it definitely has to be unsubscribed. The order in the code is maintained because if getStoredMessges function emits i am prepending it to the list of messages and otherwise appending that message